# How to make two lists of text appear side by side and lined up

Tags: spacing, multicol, columns, parcolumns

I'm new to Latex and this forum. I want to make two columns of text:

SAT:--------------------------SAT Subject Tests:

Critical Reading: 800------------Biology: 800

Math: 800---------------------Chemistry: 780

Writing: 730-------------------Math 2: 800

The above dashes were the only way I could make the columns line up. Sorry for the horrible formatting but I hope you get the idea. One column for my SAT scores, one column for my SAT Subject Test scores.

I tried using parcolumns:

```
\begin{parcolumns}{2} 
\colchunk[1]{SAT: Critical Reading: 800 Math: 800 Writing: 730 }
\colchunk[2]{\textsc{SAT Subject Tests: Biology: 800 Chemistry 780 Math 2: 800}}
\colplacechunks
\end{parcolumns}
```

However, everything just appears on the same line and extends off the page.
Please help.

Comment: Welcome! Please always post a complete, compilable minimal example as it is much more useful than a fragment of code.

Comment: Do you want to allow page breaks within these lists? Can the items be several lines long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[wide]
      \item[SAT:]
      \item[Critical Reading:] 800
      \item[Math:] 800
      \item[Writing:] 730
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \scshape
    \begin{itemize}[wide]
      \item[SAT Subject Tests:]
      \item[Biology:] 800
      \item[Chemistry:] 780
      \item[Math 2:] 800
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Please note I don't know what defines the macros and environments you've used so I've just gone by the desired output and done it as I would probably do it.

Comment: thanks so much, your solution was exactly what i wanted.